# How to use patch with the preinstall wireshark

Tags: windows-7, build, patch, wireshark

I am using win 7 and a newbie ... so I am afraid to build the wireshark again.
I wanted to know that how can I use some patch files wit wireshark without rebuilding it (with preinstall wireshark).
Is there is a simple method or building the wireshark is the  only solution ?

Comment: Why did you build it, It works from binary. Or I don't get something?

Comment: I didn't build that I installed that .. the long Linux  kinda environment procedure is scaring me to built that again :/

Answer (score 0):

The only "patch files" I know of are patches to the Wireshark source files; for those patch files, the only way to use them is to apply them to the Wireshark source files and rebuild Wireshark.